# Mongoose-mongoDB advanced query joins

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have two models in my database, the Room model and Block model

**The room schema**

```
var RoomSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  floor: { type: Number, min: 0},
  capacity: { type: Number, min: 0},
  free: { type: Number, min: 0},
  block: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Block'}
});
```

**the block schema**

```
var BlockSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  type: Boolean, // 0->man, 1->woman
  rooms: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Room'}]
});
```

I would like to retrieve all rooms that belong to a block where the type is false (rooms for men),
so if I was to write this in pseduo sql it would be like

```
select * from rooms
left join blocks on blocks.id = romms.block_id
where blocks.type = false;
```

filtering the rooms entities just after the query returns, won't work because it would change the pagination data.

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to be done as two separate queries in mongodb as it is not a relational database.

First do the blocks query:

```
db.blocksCollection.find({type : false})
```

This will return an array of blocks of type false.

This can be used to query the rooms collection for rooms in those blocks, using the `$in` operator: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

```
db.roomsCollection.find({block : { $in : [block1,block2,etc...]}})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a single query when you use Mongoose's **[populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)** method which is the process of automatically replacing the specified paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s). For example, you can populate your block's rooms using the query builder:

```
var query = { "type": false };
Block.find(query)
     .select('-_id -name -type')
     .poulate('rooms')
     .exec(function (err, res){
        console.log('The first room is %s', res[0].rooms[0].name);
     })
```

Comment: `populate()` is a better solution when using Mongoose, so +1. Although technically, it's not _"one single query"_, it just looks like one. Internally Mongoose will do the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks for the enlightenment, indeed technically it's equivalent to the two queries above under the Mongoose hood.